# HTML, CSS : Responsive header with logo and text

Tags: html, css, responsive, velo

I'm really having a lot of trouble trying to recreate this Wix site with the goal of having the mobile & desktop website responsive with other content.

http://nl.wix.com/website-template/view/html/936?&viewMode=mobile

[image]

[image]

As soon as I use a different width the 30° moves to a different position,
which means the site isn't properly responsive. I have no idea how to fix this.
Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>30 &deg;C</h1>
        <div class="clearfix"><img src="./img/banner.png" alt="banner"> </div>
        <p>Beginning application developer</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
.header {
    background-color: #7A7CB1;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

.header img {
    width: 62.5%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-left: 6.75%;
    float:left;
}

.header h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: 30%;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}

.header p {
    margin-left: 6.75%;
    font-family: Verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

I want the 30° to be below the logo like it is in the photo, but the logo and the text should become smaller or bigger (responsive) if the width of the phone is smaller or bigger.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What do you want the end product to look like? 30 degrees to the right of the thermometer at all times? text below?

Comment: I want the website to be responsive. So the 30 degrees should be smaller if the phone's width is smaller, the logo to. the problem is the positon of the 30 degrees should stay where it is on the photo but it isn't on different width's

Comment: When setting a font size with percentages, it uses a percentage of the document's base font size, rather than it's container such as widths and heights do.

Arun's answer covers how to change font sizes based on screen/window width.

As for positioning, could you make a fiddle? I'd be happy to modify it to position correctly and explain what currently is causing issues.

Comment: Alternatively, to scale the font size smoothly, you can use the viewport-width unit (vw). Unfortunatly this will scale with the window as opposed to your image, but may be possible with some tweaks. Again, if you can upload the image and make a fiddle, I'll see what I can do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the text to become larger/smaller on different device widths, you need to add [Media Screens](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

Here is an example of a media Screen

```
  @media only screen and (max-width:940px){ /* Tablets*/ 
    h1{
       font-size:12px;
}
    }
```

What this does is when the max width of the device is 940px(Average tablet size). The h1's font size is set to a different size.